# How to list images in a folder using a combo box or select specific items using browse in web page?

Tags: html, ajax

Im creating a data entry form, i would like to give them the option to select an image from a specific directory, in which they can select one image.
now i have some image in one directory, i want to know how can i show them to the user.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a server-side language to read the contents of a directory (PHP, for instance). There are many ways of doing this with PHP.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php